# How to make enable users to login and logout using sessions in slim application?

Tags: php, session, slim

I have been developing a very simple REST application in slim framework(http://www.slimframework.com/) that allows the user to login and logout. I have been trying to manage sessions in my application using slim session manager (https://github.com/yusukezzz/slim-session-manager) but now I am close to giving up as nothing seems to be working. Is there any other library or session manager that i can use with slim. I have tried slim-session-manager but maybe because of dependencies not properly available, it doesn't seem to work. If anyone can suggest me something about it. That would save my life. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use composer for dependency management? have u configured the session manager like in the example in the readme file? There is always the possibility to just use the php build in sessions.

Comment: Typically for APIs you don't employ sessions at all. See JWT, javascript web tokens.